# Configuring SMTP mail in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails application with Devise gem for authentication. 
I cannot recieve emails sent during Devise process like forgot password, as it seems mailing is not configured properly.

i tried to add configuration in production.rb file

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'smtp.mydomain.com' }
```

What am i doing wrong? do i have to add any more configuration?

Comment: Have you checked that theer is indeed a server smtp.mydomain.com that is reachable by your rails server? And that this server has a smtp service running which is also accepting smtp mail without any authorization. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Ok.. i will check it and get back..

Comment: Yes.. i do have a smtp domain and its working fine..
I am not sure how i configure it with my Rails app (Note : my smtp accepts request without authorization from within our network)
I am using devise gem in my application, devise not at all sending email because smtp is not configured...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with the below configuration in production.rb file under environment

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "http://your_domain_name.com" }

     ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
                         :address        => "smtp.smtp_server_name.com",
                         :port           => 25,
                         :authentication => :plain
  }
```

Hope it helps someone.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3/

In that railscast there is a lot of example code that may help you.

config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "railscasts.com",
  :user_name            => "railscasts",
  :password             => "secret",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```